# How do you bind a TextBox to a ListBox's selected member's corresponding property?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding, textbox

I have a list of notifications:

```
public List<Notification> Notifications { get; set; }
```

A ListBox in my UI binds to this list:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Notifications}" DisplayMemberPath="ServiceAddress" Name="NotificationsList"/>
```

In my UI, I also have this TextBox:

```
<TextBox Name="MatchWindowTextBox"/>
```

MatchWindow is a property in Notification objects...so I can access it like this from the above list: `Notifications[SomeIndex].MatchWindow`. Anyways, when someone changes the selection on the ListBox, this effectively selects a different Notification...so is there some way to bind my TextBox to the selected notification's MatchWindow property?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

one quick way is to use an `ElementName` binding:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding SelectedItem.MatchWindow, 
                        ElementName=NotificationsList}"/>
```

However, a better approach would be to create a `SelectedItem` property of type `Notification`  in the ViewModel and bind to that instead:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Notifications}"
         SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedNotification}"/>

<!-- ... -->

<TextBox Text="{Binding SelectedNotification.MatchWindow}"/>
```

Comment: Do you mind if I throw you a little curveball? Because I'm trying to apply the same concept to something else as well!

Comment: Let's say my Notification class has a list of actions, like List<Action> ActionsList {get; set;}, and my Action has an enum on it of type ActionType...how would I make a CheckBox in my UI only be checked off if my ActionsList contains an action of some enum type?

Comment: @Alexandru either put a `bool` property in the Data Item, so you can bind `CheckBox.IsChecked` to that, or use a `EnumToBoolConverter`, or use a `DataTrigger`. Would you like to post a separate question about that?

Comment: I'm slowly getting the hang of it, but what about this spin-off (threw it in a new question)? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22205303/how-do-you-bind-a-listboxs-selecteditem-to-another-listboxs-selecteditems-pro

Comment: Someone posted an answer there, but I was wondering if I had hit an impassable wall with WPF's XAML bindings or not. If you get a moment to check it out and let me know, it would be a huge help.