# How do you bind a ListBox's SelectedItem to another ListBox's SelectedItem's property?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, binding, listbox

I have a ListBox in my UI that is bound to `List<Notification> Notifications { get; set; }`:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Notifications}"
         DisplayMemberPath="ServiceAddress"
         Name="NotificationsList"/>
```

A Notification has a filter title associated with it:

```
public class Notification
{
    public string FilterTitle { get; set; }
    public string ServiceAddress { get; set; }
}
```

My UI has another ListBox that is bound to `List<LogFilter> Filters { get; set; }`:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Filters}"
         DisplayMemberPath="Title"
         Name="FiltersList"/>
```

And as you can guess, a LogFilter contains a Title:

```
public class LogFilter
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

When I select a Notification in my NotificationsList, I would like it to select the corresponding LogFilter in my FiltersList based on the mapping of the Notification's FilterTitle and the LogFilter's Title. How could you do that through a binding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you need to set `SelectedValuePath` for first listBox to `FilterTitle`:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Notifications}"
         DisplayMemberPath="ServiceAddress" 
         Name="NotificationsList"
         SelectedValuePath="FilterTitle"/>
```

Bind with `SelectedValue` of first listbox using `ElementName`. Also you need to set `SelectedValuePath` to `Title` here as well:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Filters}"
         DisplayMemberPath="Title"
         Name="FiltersList"
         SelectedValuePath="Title"
         SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedValue, ElementName=NotificationsList, 
                                 Mode=OneWay}"/>
```

Comment: But now, when you select a notification in the first list box, and then change the filter in the second list box, it deselects the notification you just selected in the first list box, and that's not the functionality I'm after since...I'd like to be able to change the filter of a notification. Is that possible?

Comment: Could not get you correctly but I think you only want one way binding i.e. when any Notification is selected, corresponding title gets selected and not vice versa. If that's the case you need to set `Mode=OneWay` on binding. Updated in an answer.

Comment: Its still missing something because it doesn't seem to update properly from the first list box anymore. So, I have a list of notifications in the first list box, and when I select one, update the second list box. When I change selections in the second list box, I want it to change the FilterTitle data item, part of the selected Notification, in the first list box to the filter I've selected in the second list box. PS, I appreciate the help so far!

Comment: That's not a part of problem statement stated above. For the posted question above solutions will work. But for other case where you need to update `FilterTitle` that ain't possible with pure binding in XAML. You should have two properties in ViewModel and bind `SelectedValue` of both listBoxes to respective properties. When selected value of second listBox changes, set the `FilterTitle` of selected Value for first listBox to that value.

Comment: I know I didn't include it in the problem statement, just something that came up now. I tried to make is as detailed as possible. I figured it might be an impassable wall in WPF's XAML bindings. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Alexandru - I proposed the same in my answer and comments. Here - `You should have two properties in ViewModel and bind SelectedValue of both listBoxes to respective properties. When selected value of second listBox changes, set the FilterTitle of selected Value for first listBox to that value.` Any reasons to deselect an answer?

Comment: I apologize. I misread what you had said in your comment. You got to it first, its true. Sorry for that.

Comment: No issue. I was just wondering what's missing from the answer to tempt you to deselect it. Have a good day..!!

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in other answers to your previous questions, you should really consider introducing the concept of a *"Selected Item"* at the ViewModel level:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
     public List<Notification> Notifications {get;set;}

     //Here!
     public Notification SelectedNotification {get;set;} //INotifyPropertyChanged, etc here
}
```

Then bind the `ListBox.SelectedItem` to that:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Notifications}"
         SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedNotification}"
         DisplayMemberPath="ServiceAddress"/>
```

Same with the other ListBox:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Filters}"
         SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedFilter}"
         DisplayMemberPath="Title"/>
```

Then simply find the appropiate filter **At the ViewModel level** when changing the SelectedNotification:

```
 private Notification _selectedNotification;
 public Notification SelectedNotification
 {
     get { return _selectedNotification; }
     set
     {
         _selectedNotification = value;
         NotifyPropertyChange("SelectedNotification");

         //here...
         if (value != null)     
             SelectedFilter = Filters.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Title == value.FilterTitle);
     }
 }
```

Comment: Ah, yes, this is exactly what you were talking about before. I see it now.

Comment: I'm trying this out but I can't seem to get it to work, but I can tell the event's firing...I'll post a stack question on this soon...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22208875/why-isnt-my-selected-items-data-binding-updating